# Pass a typesscript paramater to a (click) method in the html file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am learning angular today and I struggle on getting through this issue :

I am looking to create a table from data of an api saved in `dataCountries` and thus, I create a ngFor loop that creates the row

But I also want to make the cells clickable so that it brings the user to a different component which gives data specific to what he clicked.

To do so, I need the specific text of the cell on which he clicked which will be enough to let me give him the info he wants

My idea was to pass it as an argument to a (click) method named `myService.goToCountry(countryName)` and then do my stuff on this method.

Here's my code :

```
<tr *ngFor="let country of dataCountries">
                
                <td  style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="myService.goToCountry(Here I want the value of country.Country)"> {{ country.Country }} </td>
</tr>
```

Is there a way to do this ?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I couldn't fully understand the problem, you can just pass country.Country if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access `country` inside the loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let country of dataCountries">            
   <td (click)="myService.goToCountry(country.Country)"> {{ country.Country }} </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: omg i'm such a dumb, i think other errors didn't let me do that.
Thank you..